# Strange irregular plural forms

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm struggling with this exercise that I found in a German grammar book:
I have to combine some nouns with the correct suffix to form their plural

**Nouns:**

1. der Schnee
2. das Gepäck
3. der Regen
4. der Rat
5. der Käse
6. der Sport
7. der Schmuck
8. das Alter

**Suffixes:**

1. stufen
2. waren
3. schläge
4. stücke
5. massen
6. arten
7. sorten
8. fälle

The first one is given as an example: "der Schnee" -> "die Scheemassen".

I haven't got a clue about the other ones (apart from "der Regen" which I think should be "die Regenfälle"). I looked up the nouns in various online dictionaries but I couldn't find these "strange" plural forms (usually the ones given are much more simple, like: -e/-en).

I guess that most of these forms are quite uncommon in both spoken and written German, is that true? Could someone please help me complete the exercise?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Did you just try a "brute force" and looked up a dictionary if it e.g. knows "Gepäckwaren" and sort them out one by another? Because besides knowing the "plurals" I'd also have no clue how to deduct it spontanously.

Comment: You may rather find the singulars (Schneemasse, Regenfall, ...) of the combined plurals in a dictionary

Comment: Also not that e.g. Rat does have a "normal" plural Räte (as used in the word Räterepublik), but that's because Rat has several meanings to begin with (similar to Bank having two plurals Banken/Bänke with its different meanings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about Regen/Regenfälle. Note however, that *Regenfälle* is not a plural of *Regen*. The plural of *Regen* is *Regen*, but it is rarely used. However, the word *Regenfall* exists. It denotes, in a sense, one instance of *Regen*, and it has a perfectly normal plural, which is *Regenfälle*. So this can be used as a substitute when you need a plural of Regen.

For the others, just check your dictionary which combinations exist.